# Leaflet featureGroup().getLayers() returns empty, while object is defined

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet

So I'm trying to achieve interactive map with grouped markers (using [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/)), visually they have been added, but when trying to retrieve the group layers, they won't return anything.

Here is my code:

```
const map;
let mapEl = $('#map');
let group;

ready().then(() => {
  // Check for map element before init
  if (mapEl !== undefined) {

    // init Leaflet map
    map = L.map('map').setView([56.962838, 24.131839], 15);
    L.tileLayer(
      'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/username/ckclhvqta0nk31iqs26xd2ngc/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoicmljaGFzZGV2IiwiYSI6ImNrY2xnY3VoMTBnYmoyc3J6NmUxdDFkdjYifQ.FgrOAAAY6Xr4Ct3h5-Zkmg',
      {
        maxZoom: 18,
        minZoom: 1,
        id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
        scrollWheelZoom: false,
        accessToken:
          'pk.eyJ1IjoicmljaGFyZGV2IiwiYSI6ImNrY2xnY3VoMTBnYmoyc3J6NmUxdDFkdjYifQ.FgrOAAAY6Xr4Ct3h5-Zkmg'
      }
    ).addTo(map);

    // Custom icon
    var leafIcon = L.icon({
      iconUrl: '/static/img/icons/circle.svg',
      iconSize: [38, 95]
    });
    
    // Set group for markers
    group = new L.featureGroup().addTo(map);

    // Retrieve marker coordinates from JSON
    $.getJSON('/mock/markers.json').done(function(el) {
      if (el.length) {
        $.each(el, function(e, target) {
          if (target.lat && target.long) {
            // Parse coordinates as grouped layer (marker) with custom icon
            group.addLayer(
              new L.marker([parseFloat(target.lat), parseFloat(target.long)], {
                icon: leafIcon
              })
            );
          }
        });
      }
    });

    // Let's test if we can retrieve layers from the group
    group.eachLayer(function(layer) {
      console.log(layer);
    });
  }
})
```

Soo, the map does work and shows the markers. Also when I dump `group` variable it returns the group object with layers:

```
{…}
_initHooksCalled: true
_layers: {…}
68: Object { _initHooksCalled: true, _leaflet_id: 68, _zoomAnimated: true, … }
70: Object { _initHooksCalled: true, _leaflet_id: 70, _zoomAnimated: true, … }
72: Object { _initHooksCalled: true, _leaflet_id: 72, _zoomAnimated: true, … }
74: Object { _initHooksCalled: true, _leaflet_id: 74, _zoomAnimated: true, … }
76: Object { _initHooksCalled: true, _leaflet_id: 76, _zoomAnimated: true, … }
78: Object { _initHooksCalled: true, _leaflet_id: 78, _zoomAnimated: true, … }
80: Object { _initHooksCalled: true, _leaflet_id: 80, _zoomAnimated: true, … }
82: Object { _initHooksCalled: true, _leaflet_id: 82, _zoomAnimated: true, … }
<prototype>: Object { … }
_leaflet_id: 67
_map: Object { _sizeChanged: false, _leaflet_id: 2, _containerId: 3, … }
_mapToAdd: Object { _sizeChanged: false, _leaflet_id: 2, _containerId: 3, … }
_zoomAnimated: true
options: Object {  }
<prototype>: Object { constructor: i(), addLayer: addLayer(t), removeLayer: removeLayer(t), … }
```

**But when I try `eachLayer()` or `getLayers()` I just don't get any dump at all. Nothing.**

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Race condition. The jQuery `$.getJSON()` call takes time, and `getLayers()` runs before it finishes.

Comment: Oh, so without hooking something inside `.done()` or outside the `getJson` scope with setting time intervals, I won't be able to retrieve it. Got it. [Avoiding race condition with Ajax](https://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/ajax-race-condition/) For other lost souls. Thanks @IvanSanchez. You can post it as answer.